# golang template double parent context

Tags: go

I am trying to access variable from double parent context. 
My code is:

`dot` is `ColumnBlock`:

```
// template content
<h4>{{.Global}}</h4> // he is fine
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">{{template "column" .LeftColumn}}</div>
    <div class="col-12">{{template "column" .RightColumn}}</div>
</div>

// template column
{{range .Columns}}
<div id="x-{{$.Kind}}-{{.ID}}">{{.Text}} - {{$.Global}}</div> // here Global is unavailable.
{{end}}
```

go:

```
type Column struct {
    ID int
    Text string
}

type ColumnList struct {
    Kind string
    Columns []Column
}

type ColumnBlock struct {
    Global bool
    LeftColumn ColumnList
    RightColumn ColumnList
}
```

How can i access `.Global` variable from `column template`?

Example: [PLAYGROUND](https://play.golang.org/p/kpPPMT8al5y)

Answer (score 0):

From https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables:

> A template invocation does not inherit variables from the point of its
>   invocation.

However you can emulate globals by registering a function.

```
t := template.Must(template.New("main").
     Funcs(template.FuncMap{
         "Global": func() string {return "true"},
     }).
     Parse(`...`))
```

Then in your template code you just use `{{Global}}` whereever you need to access the "global" value.

https://play.golang.org/p/oOmWqOIKFx5